# Excel: Drop-down list with ability to type in

Tags: vba, excel

I need to cerate a drop-down list in Excel, but there are 700+ items in my list, so it would be really handy to be able to type the first couple of letters to decrease the length of the drop-down list.

Is there a way to achieve such through standart excel means or through vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBox` in Excel has this funcionality on default. Just go to Developer section on the ribbon, pick `Insert` and from ActiveX controls pick `ComboBox`. You need some code, which will fill the list for the combo box.